Are there any UTXOs that can not be spent?
I have heard that there are UTXOs that can not be spent. From my understanding it is because the scriptPubKey is constructed that way.
If this is correct, are there some real life examples on the blockchain? Was this done intentionally or by mistake? How many are there?

Related to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49625/

@Mercedes I am not talking about burn address. If you could get PK for that address than you can spend it. P.S. I do know that it is practically impossible, but theoretical possible. As I said is it possible to make UTXO with ScriptPubKey that is theoretical impossible to solve.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=671881.0

Yes, there exists transaction outputs which are provably unspendable, regardless of cryptographic assumptions (so even when hashes and/or elliptic curve security were broken).
One well-known example are OP_RETURN outputs. Since the OP_RETURN opcode immediately abort script execution, any output whose scriptPubKey contains this instruction (outside of an OP_IF branch) is irrevocably unspendable. This is a popular mechanism for committing extra data inside Bitcoin transactions.
Another example of unspendable outputs are ones whose scriptPubKey exceeds 10000. Creating such outputs is legal, but such large scripts are unexecutable, and thus cannot be used in inputs.
Whether you consider these outputs to be UTXOs is a matter of perspective however. Bitcoin Core for example detects certain classes of outputs are provably unspendable (those whose first byte is OP_RETURN, and those with a scriptPubKey longer than 10000 bytes), and does not even insert them into its database of unspent outputs as a database size optimization. The outcome of this is that attempts to spend them will fail due to "UTXO does not found" rather than "invalid script", but the block or transaction it occurs in is invalid either way.
